# How can I install a specific NativeScript version?

Tags: npm, nativescript, downgrade, tns

Im trying to install the tns 6.7.4 version, but I just get the 7.1.2 version.

I tried to do:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g nativescript 
sudo npm cache clean --force
sudo npm install -g nativescript@6.7.4
```

I also tried with `nativescript@6`  and also with `nativescript@6.7` but everything ends with the 7.1.2 version.

Answer (score 2):

The command `npm i -g nativescript` will install the NativeScript CLI. It won't update/migrate your existing project. However, once you have installed a specific version of the CLI, you can use it to create new projects with the related versions.

For example

```
npm uninstall -g nativescript

npm i -g nativescript@5.4.0

tns --version // will output 5.4.0
```

Once you have the wanted version of the CLI you can create a project that uses the core dependencies